# XSLT sorting, select next nearest

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have following XML:

```
<Users>
  <User Id="1">
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <LastName>LastName1</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="5">
    <Name>Name5</Name>
    <LastName>LastName5</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="2">
    <Name>Name2</Name>
    <LastName>LastName2</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="4">
    <Name>Name4</Name>
    <LastName>LastName4</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="3">
    <Name>Name3</Name>
    <LastName>LastName3</LastName>
  </User>
</Users>
```

I need sort by Name, then by LastName, like in SQL: `order by Name, LastName asc` and then select users nearest next (User1, User3, User5), so output should be:

```
<Users>
  <User Id="1">
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <LastName>LastName1</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="3">
    <Name>Name3</Name>
    <LastName>LastName3</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="5">
    <Name>Name5</Name>
    <LastName>LastName5</LastName>
  </User>
</Users>
```

Now I'm using following template for sorting:

```
<xsl:template match="Users">
  <Users>
    <xsl:for-each select="User">
      <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
      <xsl:sort select="LastName"/>

      <User>
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">
          <xsl:value-of select="attribute::Id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <Name>
          <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        </Name>
        <LastName>
          <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
        </LastName>
      </User>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Users>
</xsl:template>
```

but I don't know how to filter users.
Any help is appreciated.
P.S.: I use ASP.NET 3.5

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `users nearest next (User1, User3, User5)`?

Comment: @Frédéric, I produced output. Firstly I need to sort users, then take them through one, so in output I need: User1, User2, User3

Comment: Your question says you want User1, User3, User5. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Frédéric, Yep, you're right. I make mistake. User1, User3, User5.

Comment: Then please loop to my first comment :)

Comment: @Frédéric, I supposed that he needs sorted users whose `position() mod 2 = 1`, mb I was right... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="Users">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="User">
      <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
      <xsl:sort select="LastName"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="User">
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

It produces desired output:

```
<Users>
  <User Id="1">
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <LastName>LastName1</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="3">
    <Name>Name3</Name>
    <LastName>LastName3</LastName>
  </User>
  <User Id="5">
    <Name>Name5</Name>
    <LastName>LastName5</LastName>
  </User>
</Users>
```